# Why doesn't this compile in C18?

Tags: c, microchip, pic18

I'm trying to compile the following code using the MPLAB C18 v3.36 compiler.

Compiler returns a syntax error on 'char rij;'. 
But when i put char rij; a line earlier (before TRISA = ...), it compiles ...

```
void setup(void)
{
 TRISD = 0b00000000;
 TRISA = 0b00000000;
 char rij;
 for (rij = 0; rij<ROWS; rij++)
 {
 red_byte_array[rij]=0;
 green_byte_array[rij]=0;
 blue_byte_array[rij]=0;
 }    
}
```

Comment: Well, you know in C(before C99) you have to put your declarations first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with this compiler I would guess that it follows C89 semantics which forbid mixing declarations with statements. Therefore you can only declare variables on the beginning of the block.

Comment: a.k.a: put the `char rij` at the top of the function.

Comment: This guess is correct — the best boast on the compiler's web page (http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014), is "ANSI '89 compatibility". So no mingling of declarations and code, possibly no // comments (though it was a common extension long before C99) and various other changes you're less likely to trip over with common C code.